# ¿cómo comprobar si un String tiene formato JSON en C#?

Tags: c#, json

Necesitaba comprobar si un texto era json o solo texto, el programa escane un codigo QR, algunos codigos QR tiene solo el texto con el numero de identificacion de la persona pero otros tenia un formato json donde en unos de los campos tenia el número de identificación.

> Caso 1

111111

> Caso 2

```
{
"doc": 111111,
"QRid": 3854709,
"ficha": 2144828,
"uf_id": 269852,
"td": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Forma 1

1. importa la libreria `using Newtonsoft.Json`

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json
   public static bool IsJson(this string maybeJson)
   {
          try
              {
                 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(maybeJson);
                 return true;
              }
              catch
              {
                  return false;
              }
   }
   ```

> Forma 2 con C# 9 y .net 5 o Instalando `system.Text.Json`

```
public bool IsJsonWithReader(string maybeJson)
{
   try
    {
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(maybeJson));
    reader.Read();
    reader.Skip();
    return true;
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Fuentes : https://www.variablenotfound.com/2022/04/verificar-si-una-cadena-de-texto-es-un.html
https://www.variablenotfound.com/2022/04/una-forma-mas-eficiente-de-comprobar-si.html